# Writing an array to a specific csv column with powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a csv file that has a lot of data in it, with one column being a "Username" column. I created a loop to query AD and get each username and now I need to export each of those names to the specific column in the csv. After importing the csv with:

```
$data = Import-CSV .\data.csv
```

And using the loop:

```
foreach($user in $data)
```

And I use `get-aduser $user -server $server` and `if($? -eq $true){ $user = $user + "01" }`

I tried using 
`$data.Username | Export-CSV .\data.csv` and `$data.Username | out-file .\data.csv` 
but so far neither have worked.

Comment: What's inside the loop? You've described your script but left out the part where you're actually manipulating the data. It sounds like you have a complete script which "doesn't work" - show the code and explain what exactly "doesn't work."

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `export-csv` on each item.  You should create a new collection of objects, and call `export-csv` on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep all the information in the pipeline so you can re-export the whole thing.

Try something like this:

```
$data | Foreach {
 get-aduser $_.Username -server $server
 if($? -eq $true){ $_.Username = $_.Username + "01" }
} | export-csv .\data.csv
```